# Missing data during processing documentdb stream via lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, full-text-search, aws-documentdb

I want to introduce full text query based on documentdb, opensearch and lambda (AWS Cloud). I prepared small architecture:

1. Documentdb cluster, with two instances and changeStreams set on true
2. Lambda with python script
3. OpenSearch where I'm pushing changes caught from documentdb stream

I'm testing flow of the data by inserting documents via mongoshell to my collection. I inserted one by one documents (10 times) and 5th wasn't inserted to OpenSearch. I did also few another tests and I'm almost sure that not all items are indexed in the OpenSearch.

**Edit - labda responsible for reading stream and pushing data to OS:**

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host, port, username, password, ssl)

    db = client['my_db']
    coll = db.get_collection('my_collection', read_preference=pymongo.ReadPreference.PRIMARY)
    stream = coll.watch()

    try:
        change = stream.next() 
        if change is not None:
            document = change['fullDocument']
            myObject = document['myObject']

            headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            query = {
                'id': document['docId'],
                'name': myObject['docName']
            }
            url = 'url-to-openSearch-domain/my-index/_doc/' + document['docId']
 
            basic = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
            r = requests.put(url, auth=basic, headers, data=json.dumps(query))
```

I will only add that I tested also *stream.try_next()*, but it return None all the time.

I tried few settings, but still there is data loosing (lambda is not triggered or something).
My settings:

- **Lambda**: 1024MB of memory, timeout 15 min, provisioned concurrency - 10,
- **Trigger**: Batch size 1000, full document configuration: *updateLookup*

Does somebody know what can be the root cause of this data loosing? Maybe changeStream is changing to fast and lambda can't catch it?

Comment: Please show your Lambda function code in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, I added part of code which is responsible for reading changes from stream and pushing it to OpenSearch.

Comment: What's the trigger for your Lambda? Cron via Eventbridge or DocumentDB directly?

Comment: Basically after a long time, problem solved: trigger was set on documentdb stream. I changed it to trigger lambda every 60 second (from event bridge) and now all data is processed.

Answer (score -1):

I found this tutorial useful and may solve your problem with less coding on lambda function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-documentdb-tutorial.html#docdb-create-the-lambda-event-source-mapping

Follow Create the event source mapping with the following configuration:

DocumentDB cluster – Choose the cluster you created earlier.

Database name – docdbdemo

Collection name – products

Batch size – 1

Starting position – Latest

Authentication – BASIC_AUTH

Secrets Manager key – Choose the DocumentDBSecret you just created.

Batch window – 1

Full document configuration – UpdateLookup

Don't forget to check Activate on the checkbox.

The configurations is crucial information for the Lambda Trigger to  watch Up to Date Data Change on DB/Collection on DocumentDB and send the event to lambda function.

So, you need only handle event and get the data from the event object.
Here is the example that you can try.

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        data=event['events'][0]['event']['fullDocument']
        print(data)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': data
        }
```